# How to use project with different scala versions in sbt

Tags: scala, build, sbt

I'm wondering if sbt supports to have projects that use different versions of Scala.

Given the following projects

- `root` (the root aggregate)
- `project211` -> scalaVersion = 2.11
- `project212` -> scalaVersion = 2.12
- `common` (common code used by both projectXxx) -> crossScalaVersions = Seq(2.11, 2.12)

The `test` command throws an error (during the `update` task, because the cross compilation of the common module is not triggered before).

```
[error] (project211 / update) sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: Error downloading com.example:common_2.11:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT
```

The `+test` works (it seems that the cross compilation of the common module is triggered).

The same error prevents from importing the project into IntelliJ. Is there a workaround for sbt.

Is it a good idea to work with such a setup or should I split in two distinct sbt builds ?

The example code is available here : https://github.com/YannMoisan/sbt-scala-versions

Comment: I think this is a problematic setup. I don't know how to solve it well. `root` can't aggregate the task for all subprojects because it doesn't they don't all coexist on the same version of Scala. It works ok if there is one common version of Scala for all projects and some also compile with another version. Also, I think if you run `+compile` it will work. The order of aggregation could play some role too.

Comment: Have you solved the problem eventually?